# "pages=some" option ignored by backgroud package when passed using the \backgroundsetup command

Tags: backgrounds, bugs

I am trying to use the [`background`](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/background/background.pdf) package to include watermark-style in the background of my document. However, I only want the background in certain, but not all pages. Supposedly, the package has an option for that: `pages=some`. But this option seems to have no effect. The background is still added to all pages.

Here is an MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{background}

\backgroundsetup{
    pages=some,
    scale=1,
    opacity=0.4,
    angle=90,
    nodeanchor=south east,
    position=current page.north east,
    contents=\includegraphics{example-image-a},
}

\begin{document}

test1
\BgThispage

\newpage

test2

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if `pages=some` is passed directly as a package option:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

\backgroundsetup{
    scale=1,
    opacity=0.4,
    angle=90,
    nodeanchor=south east,
    position=current page.north east,
    contents=\includegraphics{example-image-a},
}

\begin{document}

test1
\BgThispage

\newpage

test2

\end{document}
```

This seems to be a bug.